# Discord JS v13 Getting var's from an object and putting them all in a embed

Tags: javascript, node.js, object, discord, discord.js

Ive never worked with objects and dont know how they work. Tried searching it up but doesnt come up with what im looking for. I want to get peoples username in sample and put them all into an embed to display whos online

```
  if (command === "status") {
    util.status('server', 25565, options)
      .then(
        (result) => {
          console.log(result)
          dumbarry = result.players.sample.names
          console.log(dumbarry)

          if (!dumbarry) return message.channel.send("No one is online")
          
          let embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle("Mincraft Players Online")
          for (let i = 0; i < dumbarry.length; i++) {
            embed.addField(dumbarry[i], 'is online')
          }
          message.channel.send(embed)
        }
      )
      .catch((error) => console.error(error));
  }
```

returns

```
{
  version: { name: 'Paper 1.18.2', protocol: 758 },
  players: { online: 1, max: 100, sample: [ [Object] ] },
  motd: {
    raw: '§fWelcome to hell',
    clean: 'Welcome to hell',
    html: '<span><span style="color: #FFFFFF;">Welcome to hell</span></span>'
  },
  favicon: null,
  srvRecord: { host: 'server', port: 25600 },
  roundTripLatency: 139
}
```

In the object

`[ { id: '8c075091-7837-41ca-9d9c-bb618843b15f', name: 'newdabz' }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't look to bad, just a few issues i see.

Since the player list is an array you need to correct this line first, 
because you can't destructure the array like that:

```
- dumbarry = result.players.sample.names
+ let dumbarry = result.players.sample
```

From there on you now have an array of the playerlist and you can use the for loop
To add fields or add them to a string.

```
// Sample 1

for (let i = 0; i < dumbarry.length; i++) {
  embed.addField(dumbarry[i].name, 'is online')
}

// Sample 2

for (let player of dumbarry) {
  embed.addField(player.name, 'is online.');
}

// With string

let string = '';
for (let player of dumbarry) {
  string += `**${player.name}** is online!\n`
}
embed.setDescription(string);
```

I hope that helped!
If someone has a better / more efficient way, let me know :)